# Date in english

Tags: date-preferences, language

Hie
When we send tax receipt to members the month of the date is in english.
What is the solution to have contribution date in french?
Regards
P. Rolland

Answer (score 2):

Go to Administer/Localization/Date Formats

Comment: That might be a good workaround if they're ok with a date format that just uses numbers, but I think what they're saying is that if they want to have the month spelled out in the date, then even though their site is in French then something like dd-mmm-yyyy still comes out as 21-January-2020. (I might have the variation wrong, but the point is the month is coming out with the english word.)

Comment: I just switched my test site to French and sent myself a receipt and it came back with the month as 1st février, 2020  - so the month is translated OK

Comment: Interesting. I just tried the same thing on dmaster (using redirect to database for smtp settings which stores it as an archived mailing) and it shows English, e.g. "Date de réception: February 1st, 2020".

Comment: My test was using 5.19.4